# Unable to vertically center my image

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I’m trying to center, vertically, an image that will be my submit button.  I have this HTML

```
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle"><input alt="Search" type="image" src="/assets/magnifying-glass-0220f37269f90a370c3bb60229240f2ef2a4e15b335cd42e64563ba65e4f22e4.png" class="search_button"></div>
```

and then this class tied to the image

```
.search_button {
        vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

However, the image is still aligned at the top of the DIV.  The image is broken in the middle, but you can see the alt text aligning to the top — https://jsfiddle.net/hLn6fv49/ .  How do I align it vertically?

Comment: [The de facto guide to centering in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: I read this guide in its entirety and the answer is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to align all divs:

```
div#statSearchFields div {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to align all the other DIVs -- I want the other DIVs to stay vertically exactdly where they are.  The only thing I want ot move into the middle is the DIV containing that search image.

Comment: The other two divs will not move. Just add the snippet above to your fiddle and try it out. When you align all three divs middle, the first two divs will stay the same because they are the same height. So all three divs need to be aligned middle.

Answer (score 0):

`.searchField {display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom;}`

align it to the bottom of the field container. And you can remove the inline vertical-align... and the align on the button itself...

**[fiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/hLn6fv49/2/)**

Comment: I don't want to align it to the bottom.  I want to align it to the middle (center).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`.

[Take a look here.](http://codepen.io/claudio_bonfati/pen/jAoJEL)

:)

Comment: On what elements am I applying these style attributes?

Comment: See the link. All what you need is there. :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , use below

HTML:

```
    <div class="test" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle"><input alt="Search" type="image" src="/assets/magnifying-glass-0220f37269f90a370c3bb60229240f2ef2a4e15b335cd42e64563ba65e4f22e4.png" class="search_button"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/hLn6fv49/4/